# How can I replace entire line of text in stream file using SQLTYPE(CLOB_File)?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I'm trying to replace a line of text in a config file that looks like the following:

```
P   235 1 example.com
```

The part of that line I would like to replace is 'example.com'. I can do this using the following code:

```
frmF_Name = %trim(path) + '.bak';
frmF_NL = %len(%trim(frmF_Name));
frmF_FO = SQFRD;

toF_Name = %trim(path);
toF_NL = %len(%trim(toF_Name));
toF_FO = SQFOVR;

exec SQL Set :toF = replace(:frmF,'example.com', :url);
```

However, I would like to find and replace by the config file entry('P   235 1 ') rather than the URL as the URL will not be static. To give you an idea of what I'm trying to do, it can be achieved with the following QSHELL statement:

```
  sed "/P   235 1/s/.*/P   235 1 newURL.com/"           
  /mydir/file.txt > /mydir/file.txt.bak
```

I however cannot use sed in this instance as the file is over 32k(it's around 92k).

The following code will search by the entry:

```
frmF_Name = %trim(path) + '.bak';
frmF_NL = %len(%trim(frmF_Name));
frmF_FO = SQFRD;

toF_Name = %trim(path);
toF_NL = %len(%trim(toF_Name));
toF_FO = SQFOVR;

exec SQL Set :toF = replace(:frmF,'P   235 1 ', :url);
```

but the file ends up looking like this after the edit:

```
P   235 1 newurl.com                                                          example.com
```

It replaces it by searching by entry, but pushes the previous entry to the end of the length of the variable. So, how can I replace the entire stream file line using SQL_CLOB?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using SQL to do this instead of accessing the IFS config file from RPG or some other language?  I only ask because SQL isn't really that great at file editing and it would make sense to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: For that matter, I'm taking you at your word that sed in QSHELL doesn't work for files over 32k (which seems odd because that's not very big) but have you tried it from PASE?